# Differentiate a Function (Help me Solve?!)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ for:

$C(1+Ae^{-bt})^{-1}$

I have tried and arrived at:

$-C(1+Ae^{-bt})^{-2}$

however that is not the correct answer.

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: Is the function $$y(t)=C\left(1+Ae^{-bt}\right)^{-1}=\frac C{1+Ae^{-bt}}\;\;?$$

Comment: You need that if $F(x)=f(g(x))$, then $F'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. You just wrote $F'(x)=f'(g(x))$, which is wrong.

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{d}{dt}$ rather than $\frac{d}{dx}$, because if you derive your expression w.r.t $x$ you will get $0$, because your expression does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the inner derivative. The chain rule is
$$
\Bigl(f\bigl(u(t)\bigr)\Bigr)' = f'\bigl(u(t)\bigr)\cdot u'(t).
$$

So you have
\begin{align*}
f(v) &= C v^{-1} &
f'(v) &= -C v^{-2} \\
u(t) &= 1 + Ae^{-bt} &
u'(t) &= -Abe^{-bt} 
\end{align*}
and thus
\begin{align*}
\bigl(C(1+Ae^{-bt})^{-1}\bigr)' &= f'\bigl(u(t)\bigr)\cdot u'(t) \\
&= -C (1 + Ae^{-bt})^{-2} \cdot (-Abe^{-bt} ) \\
&= AbC (1 + Ae^{-bt})^{-2} e^{-bt}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

$$y(t)=C\left(1+Ae^{-bt}\right)^{-1}=\frac C{1+Ae^{-bt}}$$

we get

$$y'(t)=\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{AbCe^{-bt}}{\left(1+Ae^{-bt}\right)^2}$$

You can use either the chain rule or, perhaps a little simple, the quotient rule, since $\;A,b,C\;$ are constants.